# Authorization token format in Azure RestAPI

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, rest

I am referring this docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags

Inside this documentation, there is a rest API
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net?comp=blobs&where=

I want to call this API but the Authorization token is necessary, so what is the format of Authorization token?

Comment: HTH - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri I tried that but it is giving me error "Authentication information is not given in correct format. Check Authorization token"

Comment: Please edit your question and share the code you have written.

Comment: @GauravMantri as it is Rest API so I am directly calling from Postman by adding headers

Comment: Please shared a screenshot of that in that case.

Comment: Depending on how you want to access the blobs:
- [Shared key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#specifying-the-authorization-header) 
- [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#call-storage-operations-with-oauth-tokens)
- [Shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Taking this step by step, you first need a service principal with its client id and secret/certificate(Assuming you are using Azure AD for authentication).

You then need to assign the RBAC role on the storage account as depicted in this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#role-based-access-control). For filtering you can use Storage Blob Data Owner role set at the storage account level.

You need to hit the url https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token
with a POST request. Include the client_id, client_secret, grant_type and resource as shown in the attached pic. You will get a token in the response.[image]

Create your expression as shown [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-find-blobs?tabs=azure-portal#conditional-blob-operations-with-blob-index-tags). Your expression needs to be uri encoded. For example &where=mytag = 'tesla' will become mytag%3D%20%27tesla%27. You can use [THIS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) online decoder.

Finally hit the gettags endpoint https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net?comp=blobs&where=mytag%3D%20%27tesla%27. Pass the Authorization = 'Bearer token' in the header. Also pass x-ms-version = 2019-12-12. See attached pic.
[image]

Your response will be xml format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/">
    <Where>mytag= &apos;tesla&apos;</Where>
    <Blobs>
        <Blob>
            <Name>Calling a rest API using python.txt</Name>
            <ContainerName>test</ContainerName>
            <TagValue>tesla</TagValue>
        </Blob>
    </Blobs>
    <NextMarker/>
</EnumerationResults>
```